# Spring + (what library) for JSON REST API

Tags: java, json, rest

I'm looking to make a REST API at work, and I'd like something that integrates well with Spring. I've looked at several and wanted to see if I missed anything and get the opinion of people more in the know.

So here are my basic requirements…

- Integration (or at least not conflict with Spring 3.1+)
- Hypermedia Linking (one way or another, even if it is just string fields based on a template)
- JSON (XML would be nice too) support

One more requirement…

Mapping to/from JSON. This has been the biggest stumbling point so far. I see a lot of frameworks supporting marshelling to/form JSON, but it is all straight POJO marshelling. As an example, I may want to provide a different representation of an object for different requests.

Say I want a list of all pet owners, I'd probably just want a list of people and their names, with a link to their pets. But if some other request was specifically for an owner, I'd want to list their pets (as children of the owner object) as part of the response.

Is there a good way to do this and define that kind of mapping, or do you just have to create POJOs with different annotations and transfer data from the entities to them? Basically creating a set of DTOs to represent the data for different requests?

Comment: You may be interested in the JSON-binding in EclipseLink MOXy (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html).  MOXy offers path based mapping and an external mapping document that makes it easy to apply multiple representations (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html).  Note:  I'm the MOXy lead.

Comment: This looks fantastic, and the JSON binding is exactly what I was thinking should exist already but hadn't been able to find.

Answer (score 2):

Spring MVC probably meets all your requirements - here is a good reference - http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: Can you give me a better idea of how you'd do what I'm trying to do exactly? I've looked through that before and I get how I can easily do what I want, except for the different OXM binding depending on the request. Even with spring oxm it seems like you define a singular mapping to be used in all situations.

Comment: Spring MVC integrates very well with Jackson for converting the POJO to json and back. To customize the output, the only mechanism Jackson offers is to specify custom Serializers and Deserializers - http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers. If you are looking for a lot of control then yes, something like what Blaise has suggested looks very good - and it will be very easy to simply use this with Spring MVC.

Comment: I just figured I should update this so people can see what I ended up going with. I decided just to use MOXy and return the expected response with @ResponseBody since I only have a few API calls. At home, and in the future, I'd like to write my own HttpMessageConverter to allow me to use MOXy as the JSON/XML marshelling.

Comment: I wrote few blog posts related to REST and HATEOAS using Spring Framework: [CRUD RESTful services using Spring Framework](http://azagorneanu.blogspot.com/2011/09/crud-restful-services-using-spring.html) and [HATEOAS using Spring Framework](http://azagorneanu.blogspot.com/2013/06/hateoas-using-spring-framework.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your entities (example Person.java)
2. Use Spring Data JPA and create interfaces to auto-generate Repositories/DAOs for those entities (example. PersonRepository.java)
3. Use Spring Data REST to export your Spring Data repositories as a HATEOAS/RESTful servlet (browse `/persons` url)

You don't have to write any code for the Repositories/DAOs. Spring Data JPA will write your DAO for you. All you have to do is create a very basic interface.

You don't have to write any controllers. Spring Data REST will export all of your Repositories using its own servlet.

While you're at it, use Hibernate's hbm2java to create your entities from your database schema, and create your Spring Data JPA repositories too.